# How to display actual loop count in JMeter

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We can display the actual thread by:
`${__threadNum}`

Is there something similar for the actual loop count?

[image: loop count value]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` to get current loop iteration

```
${__jm__Thread Group__idx}
```

Notice this is part of a general enhancement in JMeter 5 for exposing the [loop count](https://jmeter.apache.org/changes_history.html)

> While Controller now exports a variable containing its current index named `__jm__<Name of your element>__idx`. So for example, if your While Controller is named `WC`, then you can access the looping index through `${__jm__WC__idx}`