# how to get loop number for each request in jmeter result

Tags: jmeter

Found in some post that iteration number is included as part THREAD NAME like MY_THREAD 1-1 .However it is not capturing loop count. How can i get it as part of jtl file?

Comment: https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display actual loop count in JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57406339/how-to-display-actual-loop-count-in-jmeter)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use [`__iterationNum()` function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#iterationNumsupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-2-1-font-sup) available via [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) bundle installable via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/):

   [image]
2. Alternative way is calling [JMeterVariables.getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--) function via i.e. [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)
3. And finally you can use `${__jm__Thread Group__idx}` [pre-defined variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller). You might want to combine it with [__intSum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) as the pre-defined variable returns zero-based number of iterations like:

   ```
   ${__intSum(${__jm__Thread Group__idx},1,)}
   ```

   [image]

Comment: The 1st is ok but the 3rd option does not work for me. I add a user-defined variables with value `${__jm__mythreadgroup__idx}` and it's not resolved during execution.

Comment: You don't need to add anything, the variable is just there, you can get its value using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script). Just in case, this functionality was added in [JMeter 4.0](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/www-announce/201802.mbox/%3Cc3c38c60-1fe8-2030-4913-1343afadad03@apache.org%3E) so if you're using prior version - consider upgrading, [you should use the latest JMeter version according to Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version)